# C language copying arrays - error in code

Tags: c, arrays, copy

I am trying to copy elements from two arrays into a third.

I can't understand why it doesn't work.

I made sure that the two arrays are filled properly, but for some reason, the actual copying doesn't work- when I print the elements of the `arr3`, I get some random numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr1[10], arr2[10], arr3[20];
    int i, n;


    printf("Enter a number of elements to be stored in each array (up to 10): ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter the %d elements to the first array:\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Element %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &arr1[i]);
    }
    printf("Enter the %d elements to the second array:\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Element %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &arr2[i]);
    }
/*
// A test to make sure first 2 array are filled by the user- works

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d  ", arr1[i]);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d  ", arr2[i]);

*/
    // something wrong here, the elements are not coppied to the third array
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++);
            arr3[i] = arr1[i];
    for(i = n; i < 2 * n; i++)
        arr3[i] = arr2[i];


    for(i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++)
        printf("%d\n", arr3[i]);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `arr3[i]=arr2[i];` : The subscript of `arr2` should start from `0`.

Comment: `#include <string.h>
memcpy(arr3, arr1, n * sizeof(*arr1));
memcpy(arr3 + n, arr2, n * sizeof(*arr2));`

Comment: Watch out for an extra (incorrect) semicolon!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reading past the end of `arr2`,  try this;

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr3[i] = arr1[i];
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    arr3[n+i] = arr2[i];
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand why your code works, I don't understand why my doesn't. Lets say n=3. when I copy from arr2 I start from arr3[3] and end with arr3[5]. what is it wrong?

Comment: arr1 and arr2 have elements 0, 1, and 2.  When n is 3.  If you first copy arr1[0..2] to arr3[0..2] then you try to copy arr2[3..5] to arr3[3..5] but arr2 doesn't have data there.  Do you understand?

Comment: I do now. Thanks. 
Can't find where you mark the question as resolved..

Answer (score -1):

That's because your code is reading arr2[10],arr2[11] ..... arr2[19]  **(if n=10 )**, all these values do not exist because arr2 only has 10 values. you can use this.

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
arr3[n+i]=arr2[i];
```

or

```
for (i=n; i<n*2; i++)
arr3[i]=arr2[i-n];
```